# insert bitmaps array instead of drawables in gridview in android

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-bitmap

I want to have a list of images as `GridView` in my app. I am using my `ImageAdapter` class for initializing `GridView`.

Here is my `ImageAdapter` class:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private Context mContext;

   // Constructor
   public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
      mContext = c;
   }

   public int getCount() {
      return mThumbIds.length;
   }

   public Object getItem(int position) {
      return null;
   }

   public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0;
   }

   // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ImageView imageView;

      if (convertView == null) {
         imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
         imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
         imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
         imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
      } 
      else 
      {
         imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
      }
      imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
      return imageView;
   }

   // Keep all Images in array
   public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
      R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
      R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
      R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
      R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
      R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
      R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
      R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
      R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
      R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
      R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
      R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
   };
}
```

But I want to use my `ArrayList<Bitmap>` instead of `Integer[] mThumbIds`.

My `Bitmap` arraylist is like this:

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

byte[] data = null;

for (int i = 0; i<image.size(); i++) {
    try {
        data = Base64.decodeBase64(image.get(i).getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    bitmaps.add(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length));
}
```

What should I do for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the method [`setImageBitmap()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) from `ImageView` for that.

In your particular case, on your `ImageAdapter` class, pass the Array of `Bitmap` on the constructor.

```
private ArrayList<BitMap> images;

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<BitMap> images) {
    mContext = c;
    this.images = images;
}
```

Then, on your `getView()` method, set the image like this:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(images.get(position);
```

And you can safely remove this:

```
// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
   R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
   R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
   R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
   R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
   R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
   R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
   R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
   R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
   R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
   R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
   R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing mThumbIds to adapter, pass arraylist of bitmaps.

If you are decoding bitmaps you need to take a special care such that it is not done on UI thread. 
This can be done using AsyncTask. Please refer: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

Also, for caching the bitmaps, number of bitmaps to be cached should depend on memory available.